# JDBC Driver Not Found com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver [Jav File Downloaded] Intellij

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I run into the problem

### java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

I have mysql-connector downloaded and uploaded into module in Intellij
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL3Ah.png)

Please help me

Updated: A Suggestion From Penny is that it should be in Library not Module

Comment: M.b. it should be in libraries, not modules

Comment: Thank you so much Penny, it took me a while

Comment: also check run configuration and try in old good cli mode something like this to localize problem: "export CLASSPATH=/usr/local/lib/myapp.jar:/usr/local/pgsql/share/java/postgresql-42.2.15.jar:. ; 
java MyApp"

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post and accept an Answer to your own Question.